# Is there a way to detect if a cloud function is being called internally

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have two cloud functions where one calls the other. But I don't want this cloud function being called by anything else that that first cloud function. Is there any way for me to determine that it was being called by the first cloud function?

```
export const fetchLeaderboard = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOptions)
  .region("us-central1")
  .https.onRequest(async (_, response) => {
    try {
      const repo = new LeaderboardRepository(new FirestoreLeaderboardProvider());
      const count = await repo.readCount();
      const toIterate = Math.ceil(count / 1000);
      const requests = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < toIterate; i++) {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        } as AxiosRequestConfig;

        const URL = "myurl";
        requests.push(axios.post(URL, JSON.stringify({ pageNumber: i }), config));
      }

      await Promise.all(requests);
    } catch (error) {
      functions.logger.error("fetchLeaderboard: Error sending leaderboard", { structuredData: true });
    }
    response.sendStatus(200);
  });

export const sendLeaderboard = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOptions)
  .region("us-central1")
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
      const pageNumber = JSON.parse(request.body).pageNumber ?? 0;
      console.log(pageNumber);
    } catch (error) {
      functions.logger.error("fetchLeaderboard: Error sending leaderboard", { structuredData: true });
    }
    response.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

Comment: How is the "other one" called by the first one?

Comment: with a axios request I call the "other" cloud function which is onRequest

Comment: @MikeOttink If you could share some code snippet then it would be a bit helpful for us.

Comment: I will hold on.

Comment: So the "other one" (`sendLeaderboard`if I correctly understand) is not called by any other service or user?

Comment: correct, but I want it to have it's own memory so that's why it is not just a normal function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to change the `sendLeaderboard` Cloud Function from an HTTPS one to a [Pub/Sub](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) one: "external" users/consumers will not be able to directly call this Cloud Function.

The Pub/Sub Cloud Function would be along the following lines:

```
const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
// ...

exports.sendLeaderboard = functions.pubsub.topic('send-leaderboard').onPublish(async (message) => {
    
    try {

        const pageNumber = message.json.pageNumber ?? 0;  // Potentially to be adapted! Convert JSON value to number??

        // ...
        // await ...
        return null;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
    }

});
```

---

And in the first Cloud Function you would call the following function

```
async function publishMessage(messageConfig) {

        const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

        const topicName = messageConfig.topicName;
        const pubSubPayload = messageConfig.pubSubPayload;

        let dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(pubSubPayload));
        await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);

}
```

as follows:

```
messageConfig = {
    topicName: 'send-leaderboard',
    pubSubPayload: {
        pageNumber: i,
        // ....
    }
}

await publishMessage(messageConfig);
```

Note that you can push `publishMessage(messageConfig);` to an array to be passed to `await Promise.all()` if necessary.